# Meaning of いやしません

Tags: grammar, particle-は

> あんなにコチコチな座り方をする猫なんて**いやしません**ぞ。
>   A cat that sits so rigidly ???

I can't figure out what this いやしません is.

Since the negative form of いやす seems like a ridiculous proposition in the context I can only assume that it is いや + する, and that いや is possibly something to do with being disagreeable, but I really can't get it to make sense.

What is this いやしません? Is it common? Any more examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I might know what it means, but I apologize if my explanation is not that good.
I believe the verb here is 居る (iru), thus, your sentence would translate like "There's no way that there is a cat (or cats) that sit in such (stiff) manner."

いる is not written a lot of times with its kanji so maybe that's why it was not so clear at first. In the sentence, there is the verb masu stem (い　from いる） +やしない.

This is related to the ~はしない／～やしない grammar which you can read about [here](http://maggiesensei.com/2017/06/26/verb-%E2%86%92noun-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%AF%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-%E3%80%9C%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-%E3%80%9C%E3%82%84%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-wa-shinai-mo-shinai-y/) if you would like.