# Difficulty understanding なり in お前の妹になんてなりはしない

Tags: grammar

I have already had a look at other posts talking about なり but the dont really seem to help.

As the title suggests, I am trying to work out what なり means in お前の妹になんてなりはしない

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73216/meaning-of-%e3%81%84%e3%82%84%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93/73219#73219 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73217/a-question-about-%e3%81%af%e3%81%97%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84

Comment: The sentence is an emphatic version of 妹になんてならない. It's like "[I/She] will never be your sister!"